# trivial group torsion or torsion-free?

Tags: group-theory, torsion-groups

Forgive me for this question:

> Is the trivial group $\{\operatorname{id}\}$ both torsion-free and a torsion group? Or how is the convention here?

By definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_abelian_group), a group G is torsion-free if no element other than the identity is of finite order. I would say this is satisfied, since there are no other elements than the identity in $\{\operatorname{id}\}$.

However, Wikipedia states that every finite every abelian is a torsion group, and doesn't exclude $\{\operatorname{id}\}$.

I'm not sure if there is any established convention for the trivial group. Thank you.

Comment: This is a [too simple to be simple](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple)-question.

Comment: The answer is yes, the trivial group is both torsion and torsion-free.